# forfiles with compact

Tags: batch-file, window, cmd

I wanted to compress all the files under a directory which are older than today.
The command i am using is 
forfiles /p E:\testbeg /s  /d -1 /c "CMD /c Compact "

In the E:\Testbeg there are folders and files which are created today and some of them are older one.

I want to compress all the files which are older than today and keep today files as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The following will compact files that have not been modified within the last day, but apparently it is not what you are looking for.

```
forfiles /p E:\testbeg /s /d -1 /c "CMD /c if @isdir==FALSE Compact /c @path"
```

Based on your comment, you want to compact all files that exist within folders that were *created* more than 1 day ago. I presume you also want to compact the folder itself so that new files that are added to it will automatically be compacted.

I don't think FORFILES will help, because it uses the "last modified date", not the "creation date". If you add or modify a file within a folder, then the folder's last modified date is updated.

Comment: When i give the path it is compressing all the files in the folder.....can you please give example.

Comment: @swapnil - The command I provided does not compress files that are modified within the last day. Are you sure the directory has new files?

Comment: yes....it is mix of new and old folders...or you can say every day one folder is getting added and i wanted automatically compress the folder which was created yesterday.

Comment: @swapnil - Ahhh... I misunderstood your question, plus I had a bug. My original answer failed to distinguish between folders and files. It has been "fixed" to only compress files older than 1 day. But I gather it is still not what you want. I don't think FORFILES will help you.

Comment: @DBENHAM-thanks for your valuable inputs but i searched around this found out may be this will work....if you can suggest something it will be very helpful.